# In excel, I am trying to make 1-5 score system that when a score is entered out of 1 to 5, it compares it to a % above and gives a total at the end

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how I can have my excel formula so I put in a score below (between 1 - 5) and it weighs it from the % listed above? In doing this, it weighs its total score in comparison to the % score above?

I hope this makes sense

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My formula in cell K5 is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B4:J4;B5:J5)
```